# ¿Como marcar un checkbox de un registro creado dinamicamente en una tabla, jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Actualmente genero una tabla dinamicamente de la siguiente forma:

```
var prestamos_asignados = $('.prestamos_asignados');
$.each(response.data, function (index, value) {
    $('<tr/>')
        .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(value.Nombres))
        .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(value.Tipo_Prestamo))        
        .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').text(value.Prestamo_Descripcion))
        .append('<div class="numero_prestamo" style="display:none">' + value.NumeroPrestamo + '</div>')        
        .append('<div class="saldo_prestamo" style="display:none">' + value.Saldo + '</div>')        
        .append('<div class="tipo_prestamo" style="display:none">' + value.Tipo_Prestamo + '</div>')        
        .append('<div class="cod_fiador_prestamo" style="display:none">' + value.Cod_Fiador + '</div>')
        .append('<div class="numero_documento" style="display:none">' + value.NumeroDocumento + '</div>')
        .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td')
        .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content')
        .append('<input type="checkbox" name="prestamo_asignado" class="prestamo_asignado" attr-num-doc="' + value.NumeroDocumento + '"/>')
        .append($('<span/>').addClass('item-media').append('<i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>'))))
        .appendTo(prestamos_asignados);
});
llenarValores();
```

La funcion `llenarValores()` me servira para marcar un checkbox especificamente.

```
function llenarValores() {
    if (JSON.stringify(prestamo_seleccionado)!='{}'){
        console.log("Existe prestamo_seleccionado");
        console.log(prestamo_seleccionado.NumeroPrestamo);
        $(".prestamos_asignados").find(".prestamo_asignado[attr-num-doc='" + prestamo_seleccionado.NumeroPrestamo + "']").prop('checked', true);
    }
}
```

Utilizando la propiedad `attr-num-doc` en la tabla dinamica pretendo marcar el checkbox al registro que contenga el mismo valor que `prestamo_seleccionado.NumeroPrestamo` el cual existe en la funcion `llenarValores`

Pero no me funciona.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo lo veo bien. Asegúrate de que `value.NumeroDocumento` se está escribiendo bien en el atributo `attr-num-doc` y de que efectivamente existe un checkbox con `prestamo_seleccionado.NumeroPrestamo`. Por cierto, ¿de dónde sale `prestamo_seleccionado`? ¿No tendrías que pasarlo como argumento a `llenarValores()`?

Comment: Por cierto, modificar tanto el DOM de la página es muy costoso. Te recomiendo generar todo el HTML en un array y al final hacer `$('.prestamos_asignados').append(arr_html.join("\n"));`.

Comment: podrías brindar el valor de data para poder realizar pruebas?

Comment: el evento que ejecuta esta funcion llenarValores() cual es?